# Migrating away from closure-util

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have been building a custom, standalone openlayers using the closure compiler something like:

```
node tasks/build.js config.json build/my-ol.js
```

My application code is in a separate js file.

I have been reading the closure-util deprecation notices in the recent ol releases. Will I still be able to build a custom standalone ol, and if so, how? I understand that doing a single build of ol + my code is better, but my code isn't ES6 module compatible yet.

Comment: Depends. Do you include specific things or just the whole OL? That is what deprecation warnings are for: you can plan ahead and migrate, or decide to stay on the last possible version until you are ready

Comment: better wait their 5.0 upgrade note